# Ruby Rails 1.9.4-perf Zeus server not working, dies

Tags: ruby, rbenv, zeus

Terminal Output:

```
joe@peteimac:~
> zeus start
Starting Zeus server
ready   : boot
died    : boot
```

:After this it doesn't quit, it just seems to hang...

Zeus is like Spork only more so. It lets you load your application in the background so things like tests run really fast. https://github.com/burke/zeus

My colleagues and I are struggling to get it to work. Here is the list of commands you would type on a brand new mac to get to where I am now, though perhaps I missed something?

THE MIGHTY LIST

```
#The github links below contain guides, this assumes they are followed, with the exception that variables go in .zshrc rather than .zshenv
#Install ZSH | https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh | This means I ditch paths into .zshrc rather than .bash_profile etc
#Install RBENV | https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv | Colleague using RVM is also having problemos
#Install ruby-build | https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build | handy for installing ruby versions
#Continue setting up RBENV and install Bundler | https://gist.github.com/1384279 | Bundler manages the gems, no need for rbenv bundler
# Install patched ruby version using Rbenv and ruby-build | https://gist.github.com/1688857 | "rbenv versions" should show something like:
> rbenv versions
  1.9.3-p194
* 1.9.3-p194-perf (set by /Users/joe/.rbenv/version)
# Rehash
rbenv rehash
# Reload .zshrc, as have added parameters to it following the gist guide for installing 194-perf
exec $SHELL
# Zeus expects a few things, rails should install to ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194-perf/bin i think
gem install rails
# The init file Zeus.json mentions cucmber and rspec, so they need to be install globally in rbenv rather than just locally bundled in your projects
gem install cucumber
gem install rspec
rbenv rehash
zeus init
zeus start
# Later, when I get zeus to work globally, I will:
##git pull project_stuff to ~/my_project
cd my_project
rbenv local 1.9.3-p194-perf
bundle install
rbenv rehash
zeus init
zeus start
```

Also tried rebooting

SOLUTION SUMMARY

This problem was because i was trying to start zeus in the home folder rather than my_project folder. Doing it in there gives a different error though, it hangs. Moved to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473539/ruby-rails-1-9-4-zeus-server-hangs-after-zeus-start

Comment: Left click on the MIGHTY LIST and drag right to read the concealed text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `rails server` work in the first place?

Comment: Ahh! Running it home directory using globaly installed gems it dies, but in the project directory it HANGS instead, so I will start a new question about fixing that, as this specific error is solved I guess =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473539/ruby-rails-1-9-4-zeus-server-hangs-after-zeus-start